# Android base64 image to .Net web api PNG and JPEG

Tags: c#, android, json.net

In my android app I can change a bitmap to either a PNG or JPG and then encode it to base64.

But if I make it a PNG, .Net will give me the error when deserializing:

> NewtonSoft json converter “ unterminated String, expected delimiter :
>   ""

Now if I make it a JPG, no errors and things work fine.

In my android app the function for both is identical except the type

PNG

```
fun bitmapToBase64(bm: Bitmap): String? {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP)
}
```

JPG

```
fun bitmapToBase64Jpg(bm: Bitmap): String? {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP)
}
```

Now, I know JPG has higher compression but I can't think of any other reason. Anyone know why one would work and the other not for the same image when both are changed to base64? I would had expected the same results.

Comment: `unterminated String, expected delimiter : ""` can indicate that the JSON was truncated.  Was the Base64 string for your PNG bitmap much longer than that for the JPG?  If so could it have been cut off somewhere in the transmission process?

Comment: @dbc That I can't say. I didn't compare the strings but will check it out.

Comment: @dbc After checking, there was a significant difference in length. JPG was 5386 and PNG was 51024. Now makes me wonder how to upload PNG or maybe just use JPG since it is a picture that is taken.